# Creating a CSS menubar

Tags: css, menu

I have created a menubar in photoshop and would like to use it in my website design. 
Though i would like to make my website fully from CSS,

The menubar is simply a gray box 1920 X 100px with a border around it styled in PS, i would like to keep this border. So i have taken a 10px wide piece from my PS design which i can use in the CSS for my menubar.

The only problem is i have no idea how i would take a 10px piece and duplicate it into the whole 1920 width menubar.

Please could i have some help with the code i could use to do this.

Thankyou in advance

Thanks for so many answers already !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OiIA.jpg

He is the border i would like

Comment: You should do this without any images. You can achieve any effect with css only. provide us a mockup to help you

Comment: Can you show us an image? As far as I understood, you need a border image.

Comment: You could use `repeat-x` on the `background` property if you want to repeat an image horizontally.

Comment: You could probably do it all in CSS, using the CSS3 `box-shadow` property, for the drop-shadow and inset shadow effect.

Comment: Hi, this is what i would like http://imgur.com/d3ewSpO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the menubar is only a gray box with a border, just do this:

### **UPDATED:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menubar"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menubar {
   width: 1920px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #353535;
   border: 12px groove;
   border-color: gold;
 }
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sE69/1/)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/7LQeA/

HTML:

```
<div class="menu"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    width:100px;
    height:1920px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```